# PHP Convert Date format Y-m-d to m-d-Y

Tags: php

I want to make my date format in `Month-Date-Year`. Current format is `Year-Month-Date`. How do I do that in PHP?

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: Try [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: i guess this question will create  a shear competition to answer, and so to gain reputation. have fun :p

Comment: @Sujit: To be fair, 5 or 6 of the answers came in simultaneously.

Comment: But to be even more fair, mine was first! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$date = "08/01/2013";
$your_date = date("m-d-y", strtotime($date));
```

I hope my answer is useful :)

Comment: Slower answer, incorrect starting date format (slashes, wrong order) and incorrect output date format (y instead of Y) and it's correct? Whatever.

Answer (score 8):

```
$originalDate = "2013-01-08";
$newDate = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Comment: Hey your right, yours came first. +1 Oh and it's weird the answer that the OP marked as correct...

Answer (score 5):

You can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to parse the date. This literally took me [one Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=parse%20date%20php) to figure this out.

```
$given = "2013-01-08";
$parseit = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($given));
```

And then you can echo it something like this:

```
echo $parseit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to these two functions:

- [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)
- [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

For example (you need to update format)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 2):

`echo date('m-d-Y', time());`

For more information see [PHP's date documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
date('m-d-y', strtotime('2012-12-31'));
```

or

```
$d = new DateTime('2012-12-31');

echo $d->format('m-d-y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime()` to get your string back into a time variable.  Then use `date()` to format the time to your required format.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
date("m-d-Y");
```

This will output your in `Month-Date-Year`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date("m-d-Y",strtotime($yourdate));
```